# How to delegate the network traffic for the WebView on the Android

Tags: android, webview

The webview component is quite useful for the development on the android. But it sends and receives the HTTP requests by itself. 
Is there a way to get/set the network traffic of the webview by the native code? That's to say, there would be a delegate class, all the network traffic of the webview (in/out, including the ajax traffic) can be delegated to this class, and the class then uses the URLConnection to send/receive the HTTP request to feed the webview. e.g E.g, I could change the status code of the response to the Webview from 301 to 304.

Or there is no way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Setting a `WebViewClient`([1](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#setWebViewClient(android.webkit.WebViewClient))) on the WebView helps you receive page load/complete requests, http authentication requests, errors like ssl error, too many redirects etc. In addition you can intercept the resource request on `WebViewClient::shouldInterceptRequest`([2](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldInterceptRequest(android.webkit.WebView,%20android.webkit.WebResourceRequest)))  and return a response.

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    //method deprecated. Use shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) on API 21 and above.
    public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest (final WebView view, String url) {
        if ( interested ) {
            // url load/cache and return response
        } else {
            return super.shouldInterceptRequest(view, url);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Kiran. But the traffic it intercepts is too limited. What if I want to change the status code of the response (maybe from 301 to 304)? The perfect solution (if there exists) is that the native code could take charge of the total network traffic of the webview.  It looks like the new version of this method (above API 21) augments the API with a new parameter of Request type. Are there any other ways to solve this below API 21, (for Android 4.x system).

Comment: Causing [redirects][1] are not supported. It might help editing the question rather than a comment on the question, so that intentions are clearer. [1]: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebResourceResponse.html#setStatusCodeAndReasonPhrase(int,%20java.lang.String)